# Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=7032

Tags: php, mysql

I use this mysql:

```
(Synology NAS server) 
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket 
Server type: MariaDB 
Server version: 5.5.34-MariaDB - Source distribution 
Protokoll version: 10
```

I should use a big INSERT query (29 columns and 80,000 rows) into an InnoDB table. 
And I get this message:

```
Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=7032

Error: 2006 => MySQL server has gone away
```

We set the `max_allowed_packet: 1,048,576`

We increased the `timeouts`, but no effect.

Comment: 29 columns * 80,000 rows would be 2,320,000 bytes already if every column would contain only one byte (and there was no overhead whatsoever) – so how can you assume a packet size of 1,048,576 bytes was enough …?

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? if yes, how?